# filling UIPickerView's component 1 after component 0

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to display UIPickerView with two components But I need to fill my component which is 1 and then fill the second component(0) according to the selected index of first.For that I have written this :

```
self.picker_ostan.reloadComponent(1)
self.picker_ostan.selectRow(1, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
self.picker_ostan.reloadComponent(0)
```

First,Filling the component with id 1 and then select the first row of that and then fill the component with id 0 according to the selected index of component 1.

But it crashes at this method :

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0  {  
            return self.ostans[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]._city.count  //crashes here
        }else{
            return self.ostans.count
        }

}
```

and says :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

How should I implement that ?